# Entity Framework v2 cache

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In EF v1 when we used GetObjectByKey on our context object contrary to linq query it stored queried object in cache is there any change in EF v2 (.NET 4) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this method was left unchanged. 
For more details you can refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.getobjectbykey.aspx).